# In Java is there a way to know the values of method parameters during an exception?

Tags: java

If I have Java code that throws an exception, I can get information about each method called in the stack trace.  For each method, is there a way to know what parameters/values were passed to that method?

Comment: Part of the problem here is that parameters are sometimes "optimized away" by the compiler so there might not be a data value for you to inspect.  Maybe in debug mode?

Comment: If you have the possibility to write an interceptor, you can access the methods parameter values prior to execution and if during execution an exception occurs, catch it and either log the parameters with the stack trace or write a custom exception that adds the parameters to it.

Comment: Using JavaEE, this would be an interceptor using `@AroundInvoke`.

Comment: @Matthias The duplicate refers to C#, this one to Java